# Rhodes- Creating an action when button is pressed

Tags: jquery, ruby, rhodes

I want to increment the value of a variable when a button is pressed on the screen, but I don't know how can I do that. Is there a method in rhodes like `.click` or something like that so that when the user clicks the button the variable value should be incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you starting from scratch on this or do you have some code you can display to help us get a concept of what you're doing as a whole? In native Jquery what your asking I've provided in the code below. It's my understanding that rhodes comes equipped with Jquery and you should be able to use it's native controls.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" name="click_me" />
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = 0;
    $("#button").click(function(){
        clicks++;
        alert(clicks);
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:**
 http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/KFax4/

Comment: Thanks, the thing with rhodes is it should comply with the jQuery Mobile. So I can click the button but I dont see the output (may be they dont support alert feature). Do you know how can I save the `clicks` var & then call it on my page so that I can call into my page itself but not as an alert box. Regards,

Comment: @Dave, no I'm not sure. But you're better off posting that as a new question. If my response helped please mark it as the answer or give it a +1.